# Float div's left to create multi-column layout?

Tags: html, css

Say I want to put a random number of same-sized divs in a multi-column layout, like so:

```
DIV 1   DIV 4   DIV 7...
DIV 2   DIV 5
DIV 3   DIV 6
```

**How can I do this using only CSS, and only the divs (no column container divs)?**

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some kind of parent, then use css3 *column-count*.

```
<style>
body {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;

    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
div {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>D</div>
<div>E</div>
<div>F</div>
```

Comment: The OP wants the divs to go down the page

Comment: Sorry about the edit. It wasn't formatted correctly after the initial post. Any ideas how'd you add to float:left to create columns?

Comment: it's work only when your div are of similar heights otherwise the alignment of the div is not proper and you will need some logic to clear the div after each row of div

Comment: maybe if you get a little more specific I could help you better

Comment: The divs will always be the same height: 100px.

Comment: @NCode: More specific? I want the div's the form columns with three divs per column, regardless of how many divs there are. I tried doing it with just float and clear lefts, but no luck.

Comment: you will need a parent div for doing this, or a very very compley css, wich probabl won't be supported in every browser

Answer (score 0):

The CSS Grid Layout Module is designed for this use case: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-grid-align/

Here's a demo: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_grid.htm . It's not well supported, IE10 being the only browser I know of that supports it.

Comment: Not a helpful answer, particularly since even IE10 won't even be released till March or May.

Comment: Some of my answers from 2008/9 weren't accepted as the best way when I wrote them either... Remember that other browsers will likely support it before then.

Comment: Without using container columns, and with a vertical arrangement with an unspecified arrangement of divs, this is the best way to do this without resorting to JS or more divs. It's likely that Pauly will need to go for different solution to the problem.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=grid – right now it's at 0.01%. I bet that unless something else replaces it that it will be at 5-10% in a years time.